# Firebase Database: get all child's data from childs

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I want to be able to differentiate my `content` between `type` and get all other data but I don't know how to get past the IDs after `content`.

> I want every data from -NBC22CHEk3ebNxdlYOi, -NBC-Nfz6e5yppFlxU7S, -NBC1TVY-TzT7yfrSA3o
> and later be possible to get new video id's from existing and new users

> /content/{user_uid}/{content_uid}

[image: Database structure]

> If I want only the content from one user then I can write this:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
// url is just a placeholder for the real database url
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(url).getReference("/content/$uid")
```

Comment: You want to fetch all data under `/content/{CurrentUserUID}`? Also can you explain _" differentiate my "content" between "type"" ?_

Comment: @Dharmaraj i mean with differentiate my "content" between with "type": one of the value from video is "type" but if i have other content types aside from video i want to differentiate between them

Comment: So fetching all content of a user with a given type e.g. get all video content of current user?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I want all content with the `type` value "video" from all `user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want all content with the type value "video" from all users.

That's actually not possible with your actual database structure. All queries in the Realtime Database work on a flat list of nodes, where the value on which you want to perform the filter/order on, must be at a **fixed** path under each direct child node.

Unfortunately, that's not your case, because you have a dynamic key under the `content` node, which is actually the UID, and which also means that you can't filter on `type`. If you want to allow that, then you have to create a flat list of videos, where the UID (SIH5...89j1) is a property inside each video object. This is already achieved since `publisher_uid` holds exactly that.

In short, remove the extra (UID) level from your database tree. Or, leave it as it is, and denormalize the data. Basically create a new structure like this:

```
/content/{content_uid}
```

See, there is no UID involved. If you're new to NoSQL databases, this might sound some kind of weird, but it's actually a quite common practice.

Comment: @Alex_Mamo Thank you for your Answer. I already thought it wouldn't work, but maybe there was a solution that I hadn't considered, so I asked this question.

Comment: When you have a hard time implementing something related to Firebase, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.